# How to discover how a program gets keyboard input?

Tags: windows

I'm reversing a windows x86 binary that I can't figure out how the program is getting the keyboard input.

I've searched for the windows api functions I was used to but the program doesn't call them.

So... Is there a function that every different method to get the keyboard input calls? If not, what should I do in order to discover how a given program gets the keyboard input?

Comment: open the application in ollydbg-> run the application -> pause the application -> press ctrrl+F9 (it will wait for user input to break) -> press the key that you want to input -> app should break in the right sport.

Comment: Is it a console or a Windows GUI program? What API functions have you checked?